Creating train.cfg in mlip-2
I am trying to train a moment tensor potential (MTPs). For that I need to convert OUTCAR (from AIMD simulation) to train.cfg file as per instructions given in this (https://www.rsc.org/suppdata/d0/mh/d0mh00787k/d0mh00787k1.pdf) paper. On executing the command
$./mlp convert-cfg OUTCAR train.cfg --input-format=vasp-outcar
Processed 2 configurations

That is, I am getting two configurations in my train.cfg file. I want to know why am I getting only two configurations. What does two correspond to in MD simulation?
Following is the content of train.cfg file that I obtained,
BEGIN_CFG
 Size
    2
 Supercell
         2.863035      0.000000      0.000000
         0.000000      2.863035      0.000000
         0.000000      0.000000      2.863035
 AtomData:  id type   cartes_x  cartes_y      cartes_z           fx          fy          fz
             1    0   0.000000  0.000000      0.000000     0.000001    0.000004    0.000010
             2    0   1.431520  1.431520      1.431520    -0.000003   -0.000002   -0.000009
 Energy
        -21.770919300000
 PlusStress:  xx          yy          zz          yz          xz          xy
       -12.62279   -12.62278   -12.62279    -0.00000    -0.00000    -0.00000
 Feature   EFS_by   VASP
END_CFG

BEGIN_CFG
 Size
    2
 Supercell
         2.863035      0.000000      0.000000
         0.000000      2.863035      0.000000
         0.000000      0.000000      2.863035
 AtomData:  id type   cartes_x  cartes_y      cartes_z           fx          fy          fz
             1    0   2.814060  0.121220      0.045530     0.043622   -0.619316   -0.044651
             2    0   1.480490  1.310300      1.385990    -0.043496    0.619359    0.044724
 Energy
        -21.826365310000
 PlusStress:  xx          yy          zz          yz          xz          xy
       -12.62857   -12.62905   -12.62851    -0.00007     0.00002    -0.00021
 Feature   EFS_by   VASP
END_CFG
```


The convert-cfg command extracts atomic positions, energy, forces, and stresses from the OUTCAR file and prints them into a .cfg file. Each image inside the .cfg file starts with the BEGIN_CFG command and ends with the END_CFG command. If you are performing atomic or cell relaxation, this command will extract information about the images that the system has gone through during optimization. Similarly, for AIMD simulations, it extracts information about the system at each time step. In your case, it seems the OUTCAR file contains only two distinct ionic step. One can easily check inside the OUTCAR/OSZICAR/XDATCAR file to observe the number of ionic steps. If MD was run for 10 step, command will extract 10 images of atomic position along with its energy/forces/stresses and prints into file. One can also redo the same thing by loading OUTCAR into ase images and print into specific format. Different machine learning package reads different format to train atomic configuration against targeted energy/forces/stress.
